# How to generate a PDF for purchase order record in NetSuite ? by using suite scripts or any other way.Please advice

Tags: salesforce, netsuite

How to generate a PDF for purchase order record in NetSuite ? by using suite scripts or any other way.Please advice, I need to export this pdf to salesforce or you can say i need to attach this purchase order pdf to salesforce oppurtunity - attachment

Am expecting a suite script code where i can get for any reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use **N/render** Module for creating pdf using suitelet script. You need to save the xml file in file cabinet. Convert your purchase order record advanced pdf file in xml and save that to file cabinet.

```
var xmlTemplateFile = file.load('Templates/PDF Templates/purchasePDFTemplate.xml');   
var renderer = render.create();
    renderer.templateContent = xmlTemplateFile.getContents();
    renderer.addRecord('record', record.load({
    type: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
    id: recId        //record id of purchase order
    }));
    var po_Pdf = renderer.renderAsPdf();
    }
```